# "Темно(,) как у Обамы в бараке"

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

Где-то подслушал такое выражение и оно мне понравилось. Только вот я думаю, нужна запятая перед "как" или нет? С одной стороны, это устойчивое выражение (заменяющее собой другое устойчивое, но менее приличное), но с другой, вроде как по правилам нужна. А как надо?

Comment: типа йумор штоле?

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю, что данное предложение представляет собой фразеологизм в классическом его понимании (фразеологическое сращение). Образное - да. Устойчивое? Сомневаюсь.... Запятая, считаю,  нужна.

Comment: На самом деле, этот оборот представляет собой переделанный другой оборот, который, как мне кажется, можно считать устойчивым.